# FLARToolKit Camera3D Issues with Away3D 4.1.4 Gold

Tags: flash, away3d, flartoolkit

I've download the latest FLARToolKit build and Away3D 4.1.4 Gold, and it seems that the custom Camera3D support class that comes with FLARToolKit is no longer compatible.  I keep getting this error.

```
Error: An abstract method was called! Either an instance of an abstract class was created, or an abstract method was not overridden by the subclass.
at away3d.cameras.lenses::LensBase/unproject()
at away3d.cameras::Camera3D/unproject()
at away3d.containers::View3D/unproject()
at away3d.core.pick::RaycastPicker/getViewCollision()
at away3d.core.managers::Mouse3DManager/updateCollider()
at away3d.containers::View3D/render()
```

I've basically just recreated the supplied sample class with FLARToolKit, which has the following line when setting up the Away3D view:

```
_view.camera = _markerSystem.getAway3DCamera();
```

Seems the unproject() method needs to be overridden.  While doing that and returning a generic vector fixes the issue, it probably makes the method useless!  I don't know enough about 3D transforms and matrices to override it properly.

Has anybody encountered this issue?  If so, how did you solve it?

Away3D: http://away3d.com

FLARToolKit: http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a mouse picking related issue, because the error only occurs when the mouse is over the View. I have disabled mouse picking in the `view3d`, and the message is gone, but this let the scene out of interactivity:

```
view3d.mouseEnabled = false;
view3d.mouseChildren = false;
view3d.mousePicker = null;
```

While Mr. Saqoosha implements a 4.1.4 Gold version of the FLARToolkit